# For $u \in G$, $u^2 = 1$, $\chi u \equiv \chi 1 \pmod{4}$ if $G$ does not have a subgroup of index 2

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $\rho : G \rightarrow \operatorname{GL}(V)$ be an $n$-dimensional complex representation of a finite group $G$ (for a complex vector space $V$). Write $\chi(g) = \operatorname{tr}(\rho g)$ for the character of $g$.

If we have an element $u \in G$ of order two, then it is easy to show that $\chi(u) \in \mathbb{Z}$, since we can view $V$ as a $\mathbb{C}\langle u \rangle$-module by restriction, which must be a sum of irreducible $\mathbb{C}\langle u \rangle$-modules, but those are only the trivial $\mathbb{C}\langle u \rangle$-module, and the representation that sends $u \mapsto -1$. Thus, we also have $\chi(u) \equiv \chi(1) \pmod{2}$.

I want to show that if $G$ does not have a subgroup of index 2, then $\chi(u) \equiv \chi(1) \pmod{4}$. The problem suggests using the homomorphism $(\det \circ \rho) : G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^\times$, but I can't really think of a way how to go about this.

Here is what I have tried so far: Since $\chi(u)$ is a sum of $n$ summands that are each $1$ or $-1$, we only really need to check that for $i$ the number of summands that are negative, $-i \equiv i \pmod{4}$. Thus, it suffices to check whether $i$ is even. Clearly, this can be done using the determinant: Since the matrix of $\rho g$ is diagonal, this is just a product of $n$ factors $1, -1$, and it is $1$ exactly when $i$ is even. How do I go from here to a subgroup of index 2 in $G$?

Comment: Look at the image of the homomorphism $\det \circ \rho$. If it has even order, then it has a subgroup of index 2, and the preimage will be a subgroup of index 2. However, the image only has even order if it has an element of order 2 in it.

Comment: I see! I haven't heard of the fact that any group of even order will have a subgroup of index 2, is there a simple proof for this?

Comment: Well the image isn't just any group, its a cyclic group.  (The simple group of order 60 has even order but no subgroup of index 2, so you do require some specialness.)

Comment: And the image being cyclic follows from the fact that it only consists of roots of unity, right? Would you mind posting this as an answer, so I could accept it?

Comment: A related question (sort of the other half of this one) is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2177407/finding-a-subgroup-of-index-2-using-a-representation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $d = \det \circ \rho: G \to \mathbb{C}^\times$. This is a homomorphism from the finite group $G$ onto a finite group $C \leq \mathbb{C}^\times$ of roots of unity, so a cyclic group. If the image has even order, then it has a subgroup of index two, namely $T = \{ z \in C : z^{|C|/2} = 1 \}$. Then $d^{-1}(T)$ is a subgroup of $G$ of index 2.

By hypotheses then, the image of $d$ has odd order, and in particular contains no even roots of unity, no primitive square roots of unity... $C$ does not contain $-1$.

Phrased even simpler, $G$ contains no element $g$ such that the determinant of $\rho(g)$ is $-1$. In particular, the eigenvalues of of $\rho(u)$ consist of $2k$ copies of $-1$ and $\chi(1)-2k$ copies of $1$.

Thus $$\chi(u) = (1) \cdot (\chi(1) - 2k) + (-1) \cdot (2k) = \chi(1) - 4k \equiv \chi(1) \pmod 4$$